# nUnit Test Adapter 10 second limit: long-running tests in nUnit

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, nunit

I have some tests in nUnit that call an external program that sometimes takes more than 10 seconds to finish. This works fine when I run them in nUnit's "Unit Test Sessions" panel. However, when I use the test adapter (which has the benefits of more through error output and automatic test discovery), I get the following error:

```
The request has taken more than 10 seconds to respond, aborting it.
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

Is there any way I can extend this time limit for my tests? Is this an issue with the adapter, or with Visual Studio itself?

Edit: To clarify, I know that mocking out time-consuming functionality is the proper thing to do. Right now, though, it's not worth the time (in my estimation) that it would take to refactor my unit tests.

Comment: I've found this: [Long-running tests ignored](https://github.com/nunit/nunit-vs-adapter/issues/24), but it is talking about at least a couple of minutes, not 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with VS, as the Resharper is able to run tests well exceeding 10 seconds. This is most likely a limitation of the adapter.

Answer (score 1):

This issue (https://github.com/nunit/nunit-vs-adapter/issues/24) is fixed in version 1.2 of the adapter.